# Mouse inputs on buttons attached to the camera don't respond when accessed online

Tags: javascript, https, aframe

I have buttons attached to the camera component and while these buttons work when being locally hosted they don't respond to mouse inputs when they're accessed from https. Everything else functions properly.

```
<a-entity id="main-camera-wrapper" position="0 0 0" rotation="0 30 0">
  <a-camera id="main-camera" visible="true" wasd-controls="enabled: false; easing: 10; acceleration: 75; fly: false;" cursor="rayOrigin: mouse;" raycaster="objects: .clickable" >
    <a-box logo="normal: img/button_meet_the_team.png; hover: img/button_meet_the_team_hover.png;" position="-4.5 -2.2 -3" rotation="0 0 0" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" color="#FFFFFF" opacity="1" class="clickable">
        <a-image src="img/button_meet_the_team.png" scale="15 5 10"></a-image>
    </a-box>
    <a-box mute-sound position="4.8 -2.2 -3" rotation="0 0 0" scale="0.1 0.1 0.1" color="#FFFFFF" opacity="1" class="clickable">
        <a-image src="img/sound-on.png" scale="5 5 5"></a-image>
    </a-box>
    <a-box id="title" position="-1.5 2.2 -3" color="#FFFFFF" opacity="0">
        <a-text position="0.015 -0.015 0" value="Front Door" width="10.8" color="#000000" opacity="0.3" font="font/Eurosti.fnt" fontImage="font/Eurosti.png"></a-text>
        <a-text position="0 0 0" value="Front Door" width="10.8" color="#FFFFFF" font="font/Eurosti.fnt" fontImage="font/Eurosti.png"></a-text>
    </a-box>
  </a-camera>
</a-entity>
```

Comment: Is it possible the component JS isn't getting served from the ftp properly?

Comment: I checked the elements and sources of the uploaded webpage and it isn't different in any way. Was that what you were asking?

Comment: If it works locally, but not when served via FTP, perhaps it's a problem with the FTP/deployment somehow. Why is it over FTP, not HTTP? Do you mean HTTP?

Comment: Sorry you're right I meant HTTP.